# Compiling all TypeScript files in project and maintaining file structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs, gulp

I would like to use some sort of task runner (Grunt, Gulp etc...) to compile from TS to JS files in different locations within the same folder (project). The outputted JS files have to be outputted in the same directory as the project will search for these JS files where the TS files are.

Example:

```
lib/**/*.ts
workspace/**/*.ts
```

I have tried using Grunt and Gulp but they don't seem to allow one to search an entire project folder for any `.ts` files recursively, which is the main issue here.

Comment: From JS to TS?  I don't think that is possible...

Comment: TS to JS ofc, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the **outDir** in your **tsConfig.json** or gulp typescript configuration.

For example:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./build"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```